# Removing part of where clause depending on input

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following query in which I want to omit the filter `created_by = @searchBy` if `@Searchby`'s input is `1`. How can I do this?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[RptCashCollectionInner]
    @branchId int, 
    @searchBy int, 
    @paidDate datetime 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Id
    FROM reading
    WHERE created_by = @searchBy 
      AND branch_id = @branchId
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can short-circuit the search by element with an `or` operator:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[RptCashCollectionInner]
  @branchId int, @searchBy int, @paidDate datetime AS
BEGIN
  select Id, from reading
  where (@searchBy = 1 or created_by=@searchBy) and branch_id=@branchId
END;
```

Or, more elegantly, with the `in` operator:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[RptCashCollectionInner]
  @branchId int, @searchBy int, @paidDate datetime AS
BEGIN
  select Id, from reading
  where @searchBy in (1, created_by) and branch_id=@branchId
END;
```

Comment: I really like the one with `IN` operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[RptCashCollectionInner]
  @branchId int, @searchBy int, @paidDate datetime AS
BEGIN
  select Id from reading
  where (@searchBy = 1 or created_by=@searchBy) and branch_id=@branchId
END;
```